# a sceptical customer

Tags: vocabulary

Is there something like a sceptical customer? Meaning a customer who questions everything.

Is it correct to use this word in this way?

Comment: I don't see why there couldn't be, the customer is human and humans can be sceptical... Do you have any context that could help to answer better?

Comment: Yes, such use is fine.

Comment: No it was just the use of the word ... because I googled it to check whether this kind of collocation is possible and there weren't that many entries

Comment: no - someone who is sceptical .. a sceptical person. Initially I wanted to use "sceptic customer" but that didn't sound right

Answer (score 1):

You can use skeptical in this case, yes. If you're looking for another/a more idiomatic phrase, what you are describing (especially since it is a chronic trait) sounds like a classic example of a [**doubting Thomas**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doubting%20Thomas)

> someone who rarely trusts or believes things before having proof : a doubtful or skeptical person

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with [skeptical customer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skeptical+customer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskeptical%20customer%3B%2Cc0).

Eg ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=yMATAQAAMAAJ&q=%22skeptical+customer%22&dq=%22skeptical+customer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj51be1r43NAhVBdlIKHbEaARwQ6AEIKDAC)):

> The **skeptical customer** discounts much of what you say and a good deal
>   of what you show, is looking for tricks and evasions and won't
>   communicate any more than is absolutely necessary to get information
>   on which to base a buying decision.